# Gui JCombobox Text gets blurred

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jcombobox

Recently I have been getting into some Gui programming in Java. I noticed that when I created a JComboBox and tried to display in my gui that the text doesn't come in full. Alot of the time it is blurred, as shown as below. I have tried increasing the size of the GridBagConstraint but it still occurs. This would also happen to the button once I press it as well.

[image]

Class 1:

```
    public class load {

        private JFrame frame;

        public static void main(String args[]) throws InvocationTargetException,
                InterruptedException {

            EventQueue.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager
                                .getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    // Create the UI here
                    load window = new load();

                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                }
            });
        }

        private void loadGui() {
            JButton create = new JButton();
            create.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    SelectionView a = new SelectionView();

                    // VVPRIMARY ERROR CURRENTLY VV
                    // unable to setvisible false without the nextframe losing pixel
                    frame.setVisible(false);
                    frame.dispose();


                }

            });

            frame.setSize(400, 400);
            frame.add(create);


        }

    }
```

Class 2:

```
public class SelectionView extends JFrame {

    public SelectionView() {
        // intialize frame
        JFrame selection = new JFrame("Sport Selection");
        JPanel a = new JPanel();

        a.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

        selection.setSize(300, 500);

        final JComboBox box = createDropdown();
        JButton load = new JButton("Load");

        load.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                int value = box.getSelectedIndex();

                switch (value) {
                case 0:
                    TableTennisView a = new TableTennisView();
                    break;
                case 1:
                    BasketBallView b = new BasketBallView();
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("Nothing");
                    break;
                }
            }

        });
        // create comboBox


        a.add(box, c);

        a.add(load, c);

        selection.add(a);
        selection.setVisible(true);

    }

    /**
     * Method CreateDropDown
     * 
     * Creates the dropdown menu for the selection view
     * 
     * @return the dropdown menu used in the view
     */
    public JComboBox createDropdown() {
        String[] sport = { "Table Tennis", "BasketBall" };

        JComboBox cb = new JComboBox(sport);

        return cb;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are initialise (and updating) the UI from within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread.

See [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) for more details.

```
EventQueue.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        // Create the UI here
    }
});
```

Also, if possible, call `setVisible` on the window last, after you have established the basic UI.  If the UI is dynamic, you will need to call `revalidate` and `repaint` on the **parent** container that you are adding your components to or consider using a `CardLayout`

Some video drivers can cause problems on some platforms, if problems persist, consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: Thanks for your tip!

from what I see, re-validation nor repainting is fixing it. 
I will look into threads more as I have barely gone into that topic.
I was going to put all of the components within a CardLayout once I finish and focus on each individual part separately before I place them together.

Comment: Swing, like many GUI frames, runs in it's own thread and is not thread safe, weird and wonderful things can happen if you don't ensure that you are running within the GUIs thread (The Event Dispatching Thread)

Comment: Hmm I tried adding the line you gave and it works yet there are still missing pixels.

I've actually made a previous version of gui programming, which inevitably worked before, but currently is giving me this same concurring error. In addition, I have updated my video driver as this is the one I have been using.

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: From what I noticed, I think my java is corrupted. I've been getting corrupted pixels overall in Java applications.

Comment: From my perspective, you are doing something wrong with the API, as the other several hundreds of thousands of other people using the API seem not to have a problem....Java 7 and 8 are a little more unforgiving of thread violations

Comment: Well its not also my code but,
When i go to control panel -> Java the same occurrence happens where there are lost pixels.

I have also copy and pasted the CardLayoutDemo given in the Oracle API to test it since it uses buttons and a JComboBox and this also results in the same occurrence